# can packed arrays be passed by reference to the task in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Can s_clk be passed as argument to xyz task in below code?

```
module test(input logic m_clk, output [1:0] logic s_clk);
  ...
  xyz (m_clk,s_clk);//assuming m_clks and s_clks are generated from top
  ...
  task automatic xyz (ref logic clk1, ref [1:0] logic clk2);
    ...
  endtask
endmodule
```

Comment: all your `[1:0]` is on the wrong side of your type identifier. It is `logic [1:0]` not `[1:0] logic`. A bus clock is unusual. Did you intend to have an array of s_clk (aka: `logic s_clk [0:1]` or `logic s_clk [2]`)?

Comment: Do you need to use `ref`?

Answer (score 1):

I have read your problem, first of all you have typo mistake

```
module test(input logic m_clk, output [1:0] logic s_clk);
task automatic xyz (ref logic clk1, ref [1:0] logic clk2);
```

instead of this you have to write

```
module test(input logic m_clk, output logic [1:0] s_clk);
task automatic xyz (ref logic clk1, ref logic [1:0] clk2);
```

For better understanding I have also share one demo code for **packed arrays can be passed by reference to the task in systemverilog.**

Here is code :

```
program main(); 
  bit [31:0] a = 25; 

initial 
begin 

  #10 a = 7; 
  #10 a = 20; 
  #10 a = 3;

#10 $finish; 
end 

task pass_by_val(int i); 
$monitor("===============================================%d",i);
forever 
@a $display("pass_by_val: I is %0d",i); 
endtask 


  task pass_by_ref(ref bit [31:0]i); 
forever
  begin
    @a $display("pass_by_ref: I is %0d",i[0]);
    $display("This is pass_by value a ====== %d \n a[0]   ====== %0d ",a,a[0]);
  end
endtask 

initial 
begin
pass_by_val(a);
end
initial   
  pass_by_ref(a); 
endprogram
```

By running this example you can observe that packed arrays can be passed by reference to the task in systemverilog and its value is also reflected to it.

Comment: reference argument is illegal inside static task-function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

pass_by_val task will register the value of the variables 
only once at the time when task is called. Subsequently when the variable changes its value, pass_by_val task cannot see the newer values. On the other hand, 'ref' variables in a task are registered whenever its value changes. As a result, when the variable 'a' value changes, the pass_by_ref task can register and display the value correctly.

I simulated Ashutosh Rawal's code and the output display is given below:

```
===============================================         25
pass_by_val: I is 25
pass_by_ref: I is 1
This is pass_by value a ======          7 
 a[0]   ====== 1 
pass_by_val: I is 25
pass_by_ref: I is 0
This is pass_by value a ======         20 
 a[0]   ====== 0 
pass_by_val: I is 25
pass_by_ref: I is 1
This is pass_by value a ======          3 
 a[0]   ====== 1 
$finish called from file "testbench.sv", line 13.
$finish at simulation time                   40
           V C S   S i m u l a t i o n   R e p o r t
```